# Logic and Reasoning question

Tags: logic, argumentation

I just want to make sure I'm correct with these answers.

1. Which of the following claims is correct?

   1. All valid arguments are sound. (False)
   2. Some valid arguments are sound. (False)
   3. All unsound arguments are invalid. (False)
   4. All of the above. (False)
   5. **None of the above.** (True)
2. Which of the following claims is not correct?

   1. All sound arguments are valid. (True)
   2. Some valid arguments are unsound. (True)
   3. **Some arguments with inconsistent premises are sound.** (False)
3. Which of the following terms refers to a part of an argument? Circle all that apply.

   1. **premise**
   2. emotion
   3. logos
   4. **conclusion**

6. Which of the following is not a basic type of argument structure?

1. Chain
2. Branching tree
3. **Spinning wheel**
4. All of the above
5. None of the above

Comment: Please don't edit your questions substantially, because it makes existing answers incorrect.

Comment: There are four different questions here! Maybe consider asking them one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, questions 1 and 2 are incorrect. Since this looks like homework, I'm only going to give you a hint.

The hint is: have a look at the definitions of *validity* and *soundness* in your textbook or online, e.g. in [Validity and Soundness](http://www.iep.utm.edu/val-snd/) at the IEP.